# Hide ticks in one of many axes from subplots in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis

In the following plot

```
f, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(7,8), sharex=True, 
                            gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[3,1],'hspace':0.05})
```

I would like to hide **ax1.xticks** but show **ax2.xticks**.

With `ax1.set_xticks([])` I end up **hiding ax1 and ax2** ticks.

Answer (score 0):

found it!

```
ax1.tick_params(bottom='off')
```

do the job!